# Prop destructuring inside of react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I've added airbnb config for eslint that encourages prop and state destructuring, I like it, but stumbled across one problem when I define state in my component

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    animation: this.props.active ? 1 : 0
  }
```

I get an error

> [eslint] Must use destructuring props assignment
>   (react/destructuring-assignment)

I'm not sure how can I correctly destructure `active` out of props here?
Usually `const {active} = this.props` works, but whenever I place it inside state or around it I get unexpected syntax error.

Comment: you have to move it into the constructor ... or you just ignore the warning

Comment: @JonasW. gotcha, well if I ignore it it ignores it everywhere or I end up with a lot of eslint disable comments :/ an idea if this can be somehow disabled globally for state = { pattern?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only to keep it inside of the class property is to use a getter (which will be invoked at the first render):

```
state = {
  get animation() {
    const { active } = this.props;
    return active ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

Or you use an IIFE to initialize the property:

```
state = (() => {
  const { active } = this.props;
  return { animation: active ? 1 : 0 };

})()
```

But thats actually a bit overcomplicating. Another solution would be to move the property into the constructor:

```
constructor(...args) {
 super(...args);

 const { active } = this.props;
 this.state = { animation: active ? 1 : 0 };

}
```

But I personally would just ignore that warning here.

Comment: There is an extra parenthesis in the IIFE code block. ;)

Comment: What is the ...args means (the triple dots prefixing args) ?

Comment: @FMaz008 that's a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) or a spread argument

Answer (score 5):

You can add this rule to `.eslintrc.json`

```
"rules": {
    "react/destructuring-assignment": [
      "error",
      "always",
      {
        "ignoreClassFields": true
      }
    ]
  },
```