# Must use destructuring props assignment error in constructor

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, eslint, lint, destructuring

Regarding a lint code validation error:

```
error  Must use destructuring props assignment  react/destructuring-assignment
```

I am new to the concept of destructuring properties and I am a bit confused about how I am supposed to use a destructing approach to the following code:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clickedFirstTime: !this.props.showDefault,
    };
  }
```

Note to other people finding this on Google, I have read the following resources to help me understand what destructuring was, but I am just unable to figure out how to do it in this case:

- [Must use destructuring props assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712796/must-use-destructuring-props-assignment)
- https://medium.com/@lcriswell/destructuring-props-in-react-b1c295005ce0

Comment: You should *not* use destructuring here. Disable the rule, it just has too many false positives.

Comment: I feel like I should have a better follow up question but all I can think of is: really? Why was that rule added if it is so bad ?

Comment: Link to how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222448/prop-destructuring-inside-of-react-state   , answer by Almaju

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/destructuring-assignment.md) wants you to never write `this.props.…`. In this case, it's looking for

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const { showDefault } = this.props;
  this.state = {
    clickedFirstTime: !showDefault,
  };
}
```

But really your code is fine, and you should just disable the rule if it is annoying.

Comment: I'm not very strong on my feet yet, so I'd rather keep an annoying rule until I really know I am being annoyed and not wrong or lazy. Dealing with this made me understand destructuring and props spreading. So I guess it was a good thing the rule was there ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
  constructor({...props}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clickedFirstTime: !this.props.showDefault,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Althought this technically works, I think props spreading is a bad idea here...

Comment: you can add all props what you need, it's just example how spread works {showDefault, ...props}

Comment: I think it's more elegant than this const { showDefault } = this.props;